# How to clear up Riemann index when a specific event has been received?

Tags: clojure, riemann

I'm writing unit tests for an application which sends events to Riemann. Riemann starts up very slowly, so I decided to launch it once and reuse the instance for all tests. Therefore I need to clean the index from events produced by previous tests in the beginning of each new test.

What I'm trying to do is to configure Riemann in such a way that on receiving a special event it will clear its index. There is an API call that seems to be suitable for the task: http://riemann.io/api/riemann.index.html#var-clear.
But I am not very familiar with Clojure and I cannot figure out how to use it. Here is a part of my config:

```
(streams
  index
  (where (state "clear-all")
    (riemann.index/clear (:index @core))))
```

But Riemann fails to start with this error: `No implementation of method: :clear of protocol: #'riemann.index/Index found for class: nil`

This looks like `(:index @core)` is evaluated to `nil`.

This does not work too:

```
(streams
  index
  (where (state "clear-all")
    (riemann.index/clear index)))
```

The error is: `No implementation of method: :clear of protocol: #'riemann.index/Index found for class: riemann.streams$default$stream__9829`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead trying to evaluate `(riemann.index/clear (:index @core))` immediately I need a function which will be called when an event arrives:

```
(streams
  (where (state "clear-all")
    (fn [_]
      (riemann.index/clear (:index @core)))
    (else index)))
```

Now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in riemann, can only guess. First snippet seems to be correct, but probably by the time you call that code the index hasn't been associated in a core yet? In this case you could just implement `Index` protocol for `nil` value so it will do nothing when `:index` value is `nil`. Something like that (not tested):

```
(extend-protocol riemann.index/Index
  nil
  (clear [_])
  (delete [_ _])
  (delete-exactly [_ _])
  (expire [_])
  (search [_ _])
  (update [_ _])
  (lookup [_ _ _]))
```

hope that would be helpful.

Comment: This does not work, but you gave me a hint about what is wrong with my code. `(riemann.index/clear (:index @core))` is evaluated when the config is read. But I need that code to be evaluated when a message arrives. So instead that call I need a function which will be called later:   `(where (state "clear-all")
      (fn [_] riemann.index/clear (:index @core)))`
Now `riemann.index/clear` is invoked when a message is received. However this seems to be not enough to achive my initial goal: completely reset Riemann.